# Implementing IServiceProvider and IInternetSecurityManager for WebBrowser control

Tags: com, webbrowser-control

I am trying to implement the IInternetSecurityManager on a WebBrowser control in order to override some IE security restrictions.

I have extended the WebBrowser control (call it MyWebBrowser) and have subclassed the WebBrowserSite class (call it ExtendedWebBrowserSite), and I've overridden the CreateWebBrowserSiteBase method on MyWebBrowser to return an instance of ExtendedWebBrowserSite.

```
class MyWebBrowser : System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
{
    protected override WebBrowserSiteBase CreateWebBrowserSiteBase()
    {
        return new ExtendedWebBrowserSite(this);
    }
}
```

My ExtendedWebBrowserSite class implements IServiceProvider and IInternetSecurityManager interfaces:

```
class ExtendedWebBrowserSite : WebBrowserSite, IServiceProvider, IInternetSecurityManager
{

    // constructors omitted...

    // IServiceProvider implementation
    public int QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppvObject)
    {
        if (guidService == SID_IInternetSecurityManager && riid == SID_IInternetSecurityManager)
        {
            ppvObject = this;
            return HRESULTS.S_OK; // = 0x0
        }
        ppvObject = IntPtr.Zero;
        return HRESULTS.E_NOINTERFACE; // 0x80004002
    }

    // IInternetSecurityManager implementation ommitted...
    
}
```

---

##### COM Interface Definitions

```
[ComImport, GuidAttribute("6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA")]
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IServiceProvider
{
    int QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppvObject);
}
```

```
[ComImport, Guid("79EAC9EE-BAF9-11CE-8C82-00AA004BA90B")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IInternetSecurityManager
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)][PreserveSig] 
    int SetSecuritySite([In] IntPtr pSite);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)][PreserveSig] 
    int GetSecuritySite([Out] IntPtr pSite);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)][PreserveSig] 
    int MapUrlToZone([In,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszUrl, out UInt32 pdwZone, UInt32 dwFlags);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)][PreserveSig] 
    int GetSecurityId([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszUrl, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pbSecurityId, ref UInt32  pcbSecurityId, uint dwReserved);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)][PreserveSig] 
    int ProcessUrlAction([In,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszUrl, UInt32 dwAction, out byte pPolicy, UInt32 cbPolicy, byte pContext, UInt32 cbContext, UInt32 dwFlags, UInt32 dwReserved);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)][PreserveSig]
    int QueryCustomPolicy([In,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszUrl, ref Guid guidKey, ref byte ppPolicy, ref UInt32 pcbPolicy, ref byte pContext, UInt32 cbContext, UInt32 dwReserved);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)][PreserveSig]
    int SetZoneMapping(UInt32 dwZone, [In,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszPattern, UInt32 dwFlags);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)][PreserveSig]
    int GetZoneMappings(UInt32 dwZone, out IEnumString ppenumString, UInt32 dwFlags);
}
```

---

##### Results

The QueryService method is called when the WebBrowser is initialized. However, right after the QueryService method finishes and returns HRESULTS.E_NOINTERFACE, an AccessViolationException is thrown:

```
AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IOleObject.SetClientSite(IOleClientSite pClientSite)
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserBase.TransitionFromLoadedToRunning()
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserBase.TransitionUpTo(AXState state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.get_AxIWebBrowser2()
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.set_ScriptErrorsSuppressed(Boolean value)
```

*Note: None of the IInternetSecurityManager methods get called, because QueryService never gets the chance to assign an implementation of it. So I omitted the IInernetSecurityManager methods for brevity.*

Anyone have any ideas as to why this could be happening?

Comment: Does it works if you completely remove IInternetSecurityManager implementation? Please show us how IServiceProvider  and IInternetSecurityManager are defined.

Comment: @SimonMourier I've added the interface definitions to the post. If I comment out the IInternetSecurityManager implementation, it still throws the same exception. However, if I comment out the IServiceProvider implementation, the QueryService method never runs, and the exception is never thrown.

Comment: `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]` is useless here. However, you should add `[PreserveSig]` to `IServiceProvider.QueryService`. Otherwise, try `Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this, typeof(IInternetSecurityManager))` instead of `this` directly.

Comment: @SimonMourier I made your recommended changes, and that didn't fix the problem completely (the application would just crash without the debugger breaking on the exception, so not completely sure what causes it). However, on a whim, I also changed the data type for the IServiceProvider.QueryService's ppvObject parameter from `object` to `IntPtr`, and that change, plus your recommended changes, fixed the problem!